# Scala: get child nodes count in XML

Tags: xml, scala, children

I've XML in the format

```
val XML = 
<a>
 <b>value_b</b>
 <c>
   <c_1>value_c_1</c_1>
   <c_2>value_c_2</c_2>
   <c_3>value_c_3</c_3>
 </c>
 <b>value_b</b>
 <c>
   <c_1>value_c_1</c_1>
   <c_2>value_c_2</c_2>
   <c_3>value_c_3</c_3>
 </c>
 <b>value_b</b>
 <c>
   <c_1>value_c_1</c_1>
   <c_2>value_c_2</c_2>
   <c_3>value_c_3</c_3>
 </c>
</a>
```

I want to get the count for the children under `<c>`
I tried
       `(XML \\ "c").length`

But this gives the count for all `<c>` tags. I can't access `descendant` as  `(XML \\ "c")` returns `NodeSeq`

Trying  `(XML \\ "c" \\ "_").length` gives total length of all records. Not sure how I can access the child nodes. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** 
`(XML \\ "c" \ "_").length / (XML \\ "c").length` this gives correct count of fields under `<c>`. But, I feel it a bit clumsy. A nicer solution is needed.

Comment: What do you need to get? (3, 3, 3) or 9?

Comment: I need 3 only. Not the total 9 or list (3,3,3)

Comment: I have edited my answer. Probably it can't be nicer in Scala XPath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(XML \\ "c" \ "_").length` gives 9 (Count of all "c" children)

`((XML \ "c")(0) \ "_").length` gives 3 (Count of first "c" children)